# A way to find a flat area of the terrain before landing a delicate lander?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have a convoy of ships in orbit around Duna, and now I need to pick a spot to land a kethane miner. The shuttle that will ferry the kethane to the orbiting station is very large and I am worried that as it fills, it will tip if it is on a slope. Is there a way to tell how flat an area is before committing to a landing?

I looked at ISA Mapsat, but it looks like it only gives a low resolution height map; bumpy level terrain would appear flat. I tried using a small rover, but it moved so slowly that it would have taken hours or days to drive out of the hilly area; landing balanced on the tip of a peak or in the bottom of a dip isn't an option because I need to land two crafts close to each other.

Comment: Hi Dan, and welcome to Arqade!  We generally don't like explicit requests for mods, but instead try to focus on solving the root problem.  While probably not the case here, we often find that even when someone is asking for a mod, their problem can be solved in the vanilla game, or with one of the mods they already have.

Comment: I know I've dropped landers on Mun, and they promptly land on slopes.  And then tip over.  That gets rather annoying.  Hopefully there's a way to figure this out prior to landing!

Comment: @MBraedley Sorry about that. Are you referring to requests for new mods or to requests for recommendations for a mod? I certainly don't expect someone here to create a mod for me; I will edit the question to make it clear that I am looking for a solution to a problem, with or without mods.

Comment: Both actually.  Most (all?) shopping recommendation question are off-topic, which includes mod recommendations, and we don't want question asking for someone to make a mod.  Also, I already edited your question.

Comment: @MBraedley That's not entirely true. Mod recommendation requests are on topic, as long as there's a specific problem being solved. Of course, answerers are free to point out that a non-mod solution is possible. We just discussed this [in the comments here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130749/how-can-i-turn-off-as-many-visual-effects-as-possible#comment179205_130749).

Comment: I really want to focus on the solution to the problem here. It doesn't matter to me if the answer is a mission plan or a  recommendation for a mod that makes the task trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple rolling crashes and a nights sleep, I think I have a solution: A blimp probe. It will cruise around just above ground level, and then land on a flat spot in a kethane field. Then I will use it's coordinates as a target for landing the mining operation.

That will obviously only work on planets with an atmosphere. For planets without an atmosphere, a possible solution would be to swing down in an elliptical orbit to an extremely low altitude, with a pitch of 0°. I could take screenshots with the camera facing almost perfectly downwards, with the surface coordinates showing. Then I could analyze the photos and pick a location with a landmark to guide a very small marker probe down. If all goes well, I land the mining operation at the probe's coordinates. If it doesn't, I return the probe to the orbiter, refuel it, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Scout it out with a rover first. It does not take that long at all. My rover does about 20met/ps (45mph) It takes me maybe a few minutes of driving around to find a flat area to set up a beacon.